# How do I set a static IP address (or just get to a terminal) on Mythbuntu?

Tags: networking

Mythbuntu 14.04 LTS; how do I get to a terminal screen or a normal Linux menu? Need to set static IP address. Question was not asked during install. All I see is large character pages with media related questions, no networking. Current LAN is standard wired Ethernet. Covers some 22+ Ethernet connected devices over 3 residences. All devices set up static and working correctly.

Why is there not a simple question, DHCP/Static, during install. Seems this would solve a lot of problems.

Comment: Before I go research into possible solutions, have you first tried `Ctrl` + `Alt` + `T` as the shortcut to the shell to gain at least some control?

Answer (score 1):

Further to what @boon commented above - if you quit out of the Mythbuntu menu (multiple escapes and then 'y' to exit the menu) you should be dropped back to the desktop.

From there you'll see the main menu for the OS and a terminal is under `Applications -> Accessories`.

What I do is have a terminal auto start so I can ALT-TAB to it if need be.  To do this, go to `Applications -> Settings -> Session and Startup`.  A dialog will popup - switch to the Application Autostart tab and add a Terminal (the command for the terminal is `/usr/bin/xfce4-terminal`).